# selectDay error when using jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker, google-translate

In error logs of my product I see an error being reported with selectDay function of datepicker by I am not able to reproduce it on production or on local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of rigorous tests, found that the issue was caused by how google translate messes with jquery datepicker. A simple way to fix this is by adding class notranslate to the datepicker instance.

```
$('.ui-datepicker').addClass('notranslate');
```